# Spring boot jpa hikaricp idle connection behavior

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, hikaricp

In spring boot-jpa if I am using hikaricp pool configuration in which I have set  idle-timeout as 5 mins, max life time 2 mins and I have set jpa's ddl-auto property as create-drop, then if the connection which created the table sits idle for 7 mins, will drop the table in db?

Comment: Please improve the grammar, I'm unable to follow your problem.

Comment: Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are dropped when entire SessionFactory is closed.

SessionFactory has a data source, which in your case maintains a pool of connections. Closing a connection doesn't imply that SessionFactory will get closed.

As the SessionFactory is not closed by a closed connection, the table is not dropped.